# How to get media_url from tweets using the Tweepy API

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am using this code:

```
import tweepy
from tweepy.api import API
import urllib
import os

i = 1
consumer_key="xx"
consumer_secret="xx"
access_token="xx"
access_token_secret="xx"
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.secure = True
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def __init__(self, api=None):
        self.api = api or API()
        self.n = 0
        self.m = 10

    def on_status(self, status):
        if 'media' in status.entities:
            for image in  status.entities['media']:
                global i
                #picName = status.user.screen_name
                picName = "pic%s.jpg" % i
                i += 1
                link = image['media_url']
                filename = os.path.join("C:/Users/Charbo/Documents/Python/",picName)
                urllib.urlretrieve(link,filename)
                #use to test
                print(status.user.screen_name)

        else: 
            print("no media_url")

        self.n = self.n+1

        if self.n < self.m: 
            return True
        else:
            print ('tweets = '+str(self.n))
            return False

    def on_error(self, status):
        print (status)

myStreamListener = MyStreamListener()
myStream = tweepy.Stream(auth, MyStreamListener(),timeout=30)
myStream.filter(track=['#feelthebern'])
```

I am trying the access the media_url under 'photo' in my dictionary. But I am getting the following error: 'dict' object has no attribute 'media'. I would appreciate help navigating the JSON.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to see what all dir(status) offers? I can not reproduce the error since you did not give minimal and complete steps to reproduce it, but having used twitters api, I think json in available in something like status._json?

Comment: @MohitC I added all my code.

Answer (score 10):

You should try two things :

- Add entities to your request

>

```
tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q="#hashtag", count=5, include_entities=True)
```

- Check if media is not nul :

>

```
if 'media' in tweet.entities:
    for image in  tweet.entities['media']:
        (do smthing with image['media_url'])
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Thanks for the above. Just to clarify can we use tweepy.Cursor when using Stream class (so when streaming)? I added your first bullet point to my code. See edited code in my original question

Comment: I'm not sure but I think so, since Cursor handles results's pagination only

Answer (score 4):

This reply might be a little late, but I'm sure other people will find it useful someday. I actually didn't want to retweet any tweet with a video in it. So I built this function.... and it works perfectly.

```py
def on_status(self, status):
    #Ignores the tweet so long as I am the Author, or it's a reply to a tweet
    if status.in_reply_to_status_id is not None or \
        status.user.id == self.me.id:
        return

    #I only retweet tweets that I haven't yet retweeted. I also don't want to retweet any tweets that are quotes.
    if not status.retweeted and not status.is_quote_status:
        #Checking whether the tweet has no "media" in it.
        if 'media' not in status.entities:
            try:
                print(status.text)
                status.retweet()
                time.sleep(40) #Sleep for 40 seconds to avoid limits
            except Exception as e:
                print("Error on_data %s" % str(e))
                print("Error from retweeting")
        #If tweet has media, I only retweet a tweet with a photo
        elif 'media' in status.entities:
            media_details = status.entities['media']
            media_details_kind = media_details[0]
            #print(vide['type'])
            
            if media_details_kind['type'] == 'photo':
                try:
                    print("It is a photo")
                    status.retweet()
                    time.sleep(40)
                except Exception as e:
                    print("Error on_data %s" % str(e))
                    print("Error from retweeting")
        else: #Anything else is a video or GIF. I do nothing. 
            print("Sorry, this might be a video. Cound't retweet because it is neither a photo nor a text")
            print(status.text)
```